# Resize div to fit between header and footer

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova

I want to fit my body-container div (position:relative) to fit between the header and footer, on all screen sizes. Footer is in fixed position. The body-container should resize to fit between header and footer.

Although css is preferred, but if it's easier to do in jQuery/JS then I'll use it.
Please let me know what changes should I do in the page or if you need more info about the divs.

PS: I am using this page in phonegap to show in iPhone and iPad both.

Edit:

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Creator/HN2KR/) of a mockup code what I am trying to do. I want the #slider div to fit between #fcheader and #footer.
Since Links to JSFiddle needs code too, here's the code -

**HTML** -

```
<div id="fcheader">
    <div id="headertext">Title1</div>
    <div id="headertitle">Title2</div>
</div>
<div id="bodycontent">
    <div id="slider">Body</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <table width=100%>footer</table>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** -

```
#slider{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-color:#0067b3;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#headertitle{
    clear:both;
    color:#5E99D7;
    font-size:2.1em;
    margin-left:3%;
    position:relative;

}
#fcheader{
    background-color:red;
}
#headertext{
    clear:both;
    color:#0067b3;
    font-size:2.02em;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-top:1%;
    padding-top:0.8%;
    padding-right:5%;
    float:right;
}
#bodycontent{
    position:relative;
}
#footer{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    bottom:5%;
    background-color:aqua;
}
```

Comment: Using phonegap shouldn't be any problem, since the page won't scroll at all. And just to add, The body container is (Overflow:scroll)

Comment: Please create a fiddle which will easy to solve.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham Sure, I'm on it

Comment: Can you show your code and provide a jsFiddle link for it? - @Creator

Comment: Here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/Creator/HN2KR/ Also added the code in the question

Comment: The background color is just to check the heights.